# How to let a line end with | (pipe) in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

The problem is that a `|` at the end of a line (seperated by whitespace) is recognized as syntax for advanced line-breaks. What to do if you want to get this character as output?

### Example

Say you want to create a menu like

```
Section 1 | Section 2 | ...
```

*Note: if this is just what you want then take a look at* [concatenate link_to with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8639847/concatenate-link-to-with-pipe).

Wether or not a link is shown depends on a certain condition. In HAML/Ruby on Rails this could look like which does **not** work

```
%div.menu
    -if condition1?
        #{link_to 'Section 1', section_1_path} |
    -if condition2?
        #{link_to 'Section 2', section_2_path} |
    -if condition3?
        ...
```

### Work-around

As a (somehow dirty) work-around I changed the code:

```
%div.menu
    -if condition1?
        #{link_to 'Section 1', section_1_path} #{'|'}
    -if condition2?
        #{link_to 'Section 2', section_2_path} #{'|'}
    -if condition3?
        ...
```

Comment: Escape with \. so it would be \|

Comment: Won't work. See my comment on the next answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for escaping, just the same indentation than the element u want separated.

```
%div.menu
  -if condition1?
    #{link_to 'Section 1', section_1_path} 
    |
  -if condition2?
    #{link_to 'Section 2', section_2_path} 
    |
  -if condition3?
      ...
```

you can try this in browser:
[online haml editor: rendera](http://rendera.heroku.com/examples/haml)
or
[html2haml](http://html2haml.heroku.com)

Answer (score 3):

The Haml parser look fo the `|` character *preceded by whitespace* to signify a multiline block. You could use this to create a workaround by using a HTML character reference instead of a normal space in your Haml:

```
%div.menu
  -if condition1?
    #{link_to 'Section 1', section_1_path}&#x20;|
  -if condition2?
    #{link_to 'Section 2', section_2_path}&#x20;|
  -if condition3?
    ...
```

This way Haml won’t see the space so will treat the pipe as a literal, but the space will appear in the browser.

Whether you prefer this workaround to your own is likely a matter of taste. In this particular case I think a css based solution would be better, but that would depend on what browsers you need to support.

Answer (score 1):

Menu should be a list so make it an unordered list and in CSS:

```
.menu ul li:after {
  content: '|';
}
```

Comment: This is a kind of alternative solution. Especially I like the markup-aspect about it. On the other hand one could run into compability problems with some browsers (e.g. text-based).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape this character. Try "\|".

Comment: This won't work. From the [documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#escaping_):
_The backslash character escapes the first character of a line, allowing use of otherwise interpreted characters as plain text._