# HAML - showing "|"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Very quick question concerning HAML. I'm trying to get a pipe "|" to show on my page but HAML seems to be ignoring it...

In .erb I would have written something like this:

```
<h3>Account |
      <%= link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav" %></h3>
    <% end %>
```

In order to show:

Account | Log in

But in HAML it's just ignoring it and showing:

Account Log in

This is the HAML code I'm trying:

```
%h3
   Account |
   = link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The same problem is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388672/how-to-let-a-line-end-with-pipe-in-haml). In my opinion the best solution to you problem is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12409121/1677069).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "|" (pipe) character in HAML is used to merge lines in your code into one single line. You can try to escape the pipe character by using `&#124;`.

In the end your code should look like this:

```
%h3
  Account &#124;
  = link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do like this:

```
%h3
  Account
  |
  = link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav"
```

Or replace space by its HTML code:

```
%h3
  Account&#x20;|
   = link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
%h3
    Account
    |
    = link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav"
```